# Getting the tab URL back to the event script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make an extension that simply gets the URL of the current tab, parses it to get the numerical ID, and opens a new tab with a URL based on that ID.

Using an event.js script that executes inject.js and the latter should get and return the URL. Based on some other sample code I'm able to return other stuff, but I can't figure out the best way to simply return the URL of the tab. Here's the inject.js code:

```
var injected = injected || (function(){
var methods = {};

methods.gettheurl = function(){

???

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  var data = {};
  if (methods.hasOwnProperty(request.method))
    data = methods[request.method]();
  sendResponse({ data: data });
  return true;
});

return true;
})();
```

Any suggestions as to the best method for getting the URL?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking exaclty. How to get the URL? Something like `location.href`?

Comment: Yes, I think what I would like (speaking as a JavaScript novice) is to retrieve the tab URL and then receiving the same URL in the event.js script of the extension.

Comment: No, unfortunately I did not. Will try again and see where it fails.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way of getting the URL of the [current tab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) is to use '*chrome.tabs.query()'*. Dont forget to have 'tabs' permission in your manifest file.

Sample code snippet for Tabs permission:

```
"permissions": [
"tabs"
]
```